# Parsing an activation_key in url patter

Tags: python, django

anyone who knows how i can parse an activation key for an email_activation_view in django 2.2 ,
I have tried as below but am getting a 404:

```
path('accounts/activate/<activation_key>\w+/$', accounts_views.ActivationView, name='activate')
```

Test url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/activate/jkhkgjklhfdrtiufyrcd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use regex with `path()` method. Just specify `srt` path converter instead:

```
path('accounts/activate/<str:activation_key>', accounts_views.ActivationView, name='activate'
```

url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/activate/jkhkgjklhfdrtiufyrcd/
```

Check examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example).